# Sorting in Ascending and Descending order

Tags: manual-testing

In Name header column, performing a sort in Ascending or Descending order. So if now I am on the 5th page and performing the sort by Ascending order, should the 5th-page remain or the 1st page should display?

**How do I know what the correct behavior of the sorting function is?**

Comment: You determine the correct behavior by asking someone who is more familiar with your product's requirements than you are, e.g. maybe a product manager.  The people who show up on sqa.stackexchange.com don't know your product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know the correct behavior of such tricky scenarios one can only judge with experience. While working in a Software testing company have faced many such kind of challenges. 
So adding my suggestion for your test and hoping it will help you:-
User should remains on same page from where sorting has been performed.In your provided test example, user should remain on 5th page and the sorted result should be displayed as per the selection(Ascending/Descending).

Answer (score 1):

In testing, ideally you should know the expected behavior/outcome of your test before you even start testing.

So, if you're testing a functionality and you're not sure how it should respond, the solution is simple: find a [test oracle](http://istqb-glossary-explanations.blogspot.be/2016/07/test-oracle.html) for your product and find out what the expected behavior is for the Name column sorting.